# Compare string firestore with React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to check if the task I want to add is already exist in firestore (Tasks collection) according to the name of the task (task). When I display *documentSnapshot.exists*, it's undefined

```
addTask=async(task)=>{
    var useruid=firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    console.log("task : "+task);
    try{
        await firebase.firestore().collection("Tasks").where('task','==',task).get().then(documentSnapshot=>{
        {console.log('Task exists : ',documentSnapshot.exists)}
        if(documentSnapshot.exists)
        {console.log('This task already exists!')}
        else{
          firebase.firestore().collection('Tasks').add({userProducer:useruid,task:task}).then(() => {
            console.log('Task added!');
          })
      }

    })
  }
  catch(error){
    console.log("error = "+error)
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check documentSnapshot length instead of exists**

```
addTask = async (task) => {
  var useruid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  console.log("task : " + task);
 try {
   await firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("Tasks")
  .where("task", "==", task)
  .get()
  .then((documentSnapshot) => {
      console.log("Task exists : ", documentSnapshot.docs.length);
    if (documentSnapshot.docs.length > 0) {

      console.log("This task already exists!");
    
    } else {
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("Tasks")
        .add({ userProducer: useruid, task: task })
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Task added!");
        });
     }
   });
   } catch (error) {
     console.log("error = " + error);
  }
 };
```